# How to Filter an Array by Another in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state, spread

Everything that I push into `arr1` should have been removed from the mapping of `arr2`, but instead the new pushed value is returned. Why is that?

```
const [arr1, setArr1] = React.useState([]);
const arr2= ['banana', 'coconut', 'milk']

React.useEffect(() => {
    initList()
}, [])

function add (t) {
    setArr1(...arr1, t.currentTarget.value)
    console.log('arr1: ' + arr1)
}

function initList () {
    setArr1(arr2.filter(arr2 => !(arr1.includes(arr2))).map(arr2 => 
        <li>
            <input
                onChange={add} 
                type='radio'
                name='arr1'
                value={arr2}
                id={arr2}
            />
            <label
                for={arr2}
            >
                {arr2}
            </label>
        </li>
    ));
}

return (
    <div>
        {arr1}
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do not keep the JSX elements in state (arr1). state variable to just have the data only.
2. setArr1(...arr1, t.currentTarget.value) --> Not setting as array here. Update to setArr1([...arr1, t.currentTarget.value])

Try the snippet.

```js
const Test = () => {
const [arr1, setArr1] = React.useState([]);
const arr2= ['banana', 'coconut', 'milk']

function add (t) {
    setArr1([...arr1, t.currentTarget.value])
    console.log('arr1: ' + arr1)
}


return (
    <div>
        {arr2.filter(arr2 => !(arr1.includes(arr2))).map(arr2 => 
        <li>
            <input
                onChange={add} 
                type='radio'
                name='arr1'
                value={arr2}
                id={arr2}
            />
            <label
                for={arr2}
            >
                {arr2}
            </label>
        </li>
    )}
    </div>
)
};

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"> </div>
```